# How to make this code more functional or 'prettier'

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int, pretty-print

I've been working on a project where I need on a button press that this line gets executed.

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text == "0") //Checks to see Value
{
    listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text = "1";// If Value is Greater, Increase and Change ListView
    questionNumberLabel.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;// Increase and Change Label
}
```

Now I have this repeated about 10 times with each value increasing by one. But I know that this is ugly, and dysfunctional. As well as conflates the file size. I've tried a few things. Primarily this method.

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text == "0")
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 100;)
    {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text, out i))
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        i++;

        listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text = i.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

But instead of just adding one, it does the 100 instances and ends. The reason this is becoming a pain in the *** is because the

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text
```

is just that - it's a string, not an int. That's why I parsed it and tried to run it like that. But it still isn't having the out come I want.

I've also tried this

```
string listViewItemToChange = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
```

Then parsing the string, to make it prettier. It worked like it did before, but still hasn't given me the outcome I want. Which to reiterate is, I'm wanting the String taken from the list view to be changed into an int, used in the for loop, add 1, then restring it and output it on my listView.

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want the text from a listview subitem converted to an int which is then used in a loop

so - first your creating your loop variable, i, then in your loop you're assigning to it potentially 3 different values 2 of which are negated by the, i++. None of it makes sense and you shouldn't be manipulating your loop variable like that (unless understand what you're doing).

if you move statements around a little..

```
int itemsToCheck = 10; // "Now I have this repeated about 10 times "

for (var item = 0; item < itemsToCheck; item++)
        {
            int i;                
            if (!Int32.TryParse(listView1.SelectedItems[item].SubItems[3].Text, out i))
            {
                i = 0;
            }

            i++;

            listView1.SelectedItems[item].SubItems[3].Text = i.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

---

Something along those lines is what you're looking for. I haven't changed what your code does with i, just added a loop count itemsToCheck and used a different loop variable so your loop variable and parsed value are not one in the same which will likely be buggy.

Comment: Thank you so much! Honestly didn't even realize the if statement itself was an issue. +1

Comment: you're welcome Billy, glad that helped. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this give you an idea. You can start using this syntax from C# 7.0

```
var s = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
var isNumeric = int.TryParse(s, out int n);
if(isNumeric is true && n > 0){
   questionNumberLabel.Text = s;
}
```

to shortcut more

```
var s = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;     
if(int.TryParse(s, out int n) && n > 0){
   questionNumberLabel.Text = s;
}
```